# Upgrading the Character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a few scripts which are divided between the Player and the game objects Underneath player. The scripts are the accuracy, player speed, and Projectile Damage.

I have created a menu where the player (When interacted with an NPC) could buy certain upgrades to increase these values throughout the whole game.

Now I am wondering, is it better to transfer all of these scripts to 1 script and access that. Or is it better to leave it divided between the scripts and call them all independently?

Since this is my first time upgrading player stats any help is welcome!

Lets start off with the Player Script where the max Run speed is.

```
public class Player : Actor {

    public int playerNumber = 1;

    // Run Speed & Acceleration
    public float MaxRun = 90f; // Maximun Horizontal Run Speed
    public float RunAccel = 1000f; // Horizontal Acceleration Speed
    public float RunReduce = 400f; // Horizontal Acceleration when you're already when your horizontal speed is higher or equal to the maximum
```

The second script I have is in the weapon itself where I have the accuracy of the weapon.

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    protected float currentAngle = 0f;
    public float randomAngle = 20;
```

The last Script is where I have put the damage. Since the damage is within the projectile's I put everything in the projectile script.

```
//[RequireComponent (typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header ("Speed")]
    public float baseSpeed;
    public float randomSpeed;
    public Vector2 SpeedV2;
    public Vector2 Direction;

    [Header ("Damage")]
    public int DamageOnHit;
```

To put everything within my Upgrademenu I made a script calling the different scripts.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpgradeMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text accuracyText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text speedText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text damageText;

    [SerializeField]
    private float accuracyMultiplier = 0.7f;

    private Weapon weapon;
    private Projectile projectile;
    private Player player;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }

    void UpdateValues ()
    {
      accuracyText.text = weapon.randomAngle.ToString();
      damageText.text = projectile.DamageOnHit.ToString();
      speedText.text = player.MaxRun.ToString();

    }

    public void UpgradeAccuracy ()
    {
      weapon.randomAngle = (int)weapon.randomAngle * accuracyMultiplier;
      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeDamage ()
    {
      projectile.DamageOnHit = (int)projectile.DamageOnHit + 1;
      UpdateValues();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the way I'm trying to call my other scripts within the UpgradeMenu script is wrong. So if anyone is able to help that would be great!

As you can see the machinegun is a child of the player. Because you are able to pick up this item. This already causes an issue with the gun. Since I can change the value from within Unity, but when I pick up another machine gun, this value goes back to the usual 4 value.

[image: Random Angle]

Aside from that, I have a button which has an onclick value. The idea is that when a player clicks on this button (Still need to change the UI) the value should be changed with the use of this UpgradeMenu script.

[image: Random Angle]

For now the buttons work, the only problem is that the upgrade functionalities "are not set to an instance of an object"

[image: Random Angle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should distinguish between **configuration data**, and **logic data**.

- **Configuration data** does not change. e.g. Weapon magazine size.
- **Logic data** does change. e.g. Bullets in the magazine.

Logic data is unique and only exists within some object instance, while configuration data exists in a database and is identifying by an `id`.

The following is just an example code that demonstrates the idea.

Data:

```
public class WeaponData
{
    public string id;
    public float spread;
    public string projectileId;
}

public class ProjectileData
{
    public string id;
    public int damage;
    public string prefabPath;
}
```

Library:

```
public static class Library
{
    public static Dictionary<string, WeaponData> Weapons;
    public static Dictionary<string, ProjectileData> Projectiles;
    // add more ...
}
```

Configuration Setup:

```
WeaponData weapon = new WeaponData
{
    id = "shotgun",
    spread = 20f,
    projectileId = "shotgun_shell"
};

ProjectileData projectile = new ProjectileData
{
    id = "shotgun_shell",
    damage = 100,
    prefabPath = "Projectiles/ShotgunShell"
};

Library.Weapons.Add(weapon.id, weapon);
Library.Weapons.Add(projectile.id, projectile);
```

Logic:

```
public class Weapon
{
    public WeaponData weapon = Library.Weapons["shotgun"];

    public void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject.Instantiate(
            Resources.Load<Projectile>(Library.Projectiles[weapon.projectileId].prefabPath)
        );
    }
}
```

---

For an upgrade system to work, you could setup multiple weapons:

`"shotgun_v1"` -> `"shotgun_v2"` -> `"shotgun_v3"`

---

Note: Another approach would be to use [ScriptableObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html), that is if you like serializing data in the Unity editor. Cool [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY) on the topic.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get the data from the user gameObject (Which all the scripts are attached to) and to change it with another script when a purchase is being made? 

Because I made it possible that the GameManager sets the data over from 1 scene to another. This way every update made to the character will stay unless the character is dead.

Comment: @mafiaf there are many ways to achieve the same thing. In general, do what is simple and is understandable to you. If anything I just hope you realize the importance of separating config and logic data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue lies where you're trying to set randomAngle on a class type, which is not a static property:

```
public void UpgradeAccuracy ()
{
  Weapon.randomAngle = (int)Weapon.randomAngle * accuracyMultiplier;
  UpdateValues();
}
```

What is `Weapon` here? Just a class name, you can't set or get these things since it's not instantiated. What I believe you want to do is:

```
public void UpgradeAccuracy ()
{
  angle.randomAngle = (int)angle.randomAngle * accuracyMultiplier;
  UpdateValues();
}
```

Other than that, there are probably not much wrong with what you're doing. It's probably not the architecture I'd choose but I haven't seen your entire game and there might be a reason for your choices; a tip for the future would be that not everything has to be Components (derive from MonoBehaviour), you can work with "normal" classes as well when creating games in Unity if you don't need the component behaviour. I generally try to keep as few MonoBehaviour components scripts as possible.

Comment: Hello! Weapon in this case is a reference to the weapon script. I wanted to use the randomAngle component of the script to be able to change it in this case.

I will provide some screenshots so that maybe it's easier to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: In the code you pasted `Weapon` is not a reference.

Comment: I changed everything now, The idea is to change the value of Randomangle within the weapon script through the use of the UI Button. This, unfortunately, does not trigger yet. And even if it did trigger the value does not maintain when I pick up another weapon.

It should be able to change for the rest of the game until you die. (I have a gameManager which transfers data from one scene to another)

Comment: Oh, so you're actually not upgrading the _weapon_ but the player - since the player will have upgraded accuracy on all weapos, not just the currently picked up one? 

Yes, then you need to move the stats to the player or the gameManager or somewhere that persists. And when picking up a new weapon  you initialize that weapon with the stats from the player, or just let the weapon read the stats from the player constantly, so it is also affected by newer upgrades.

Comment: Regarding the null exception; you need to set the variables before you read them. `private Weapon weapon` is never set, so it will be null if you read it - but I'm guessing you understand this and your question is regarding the architecture of your current solution. I'd say re-think everything and put the properties where they should be :)

Comment: I agree with putting it on the character, the problem is that different weapons have different stats. And if I put a static number on the player, won't this cause problem with ALL weapon statistics? So to say my shotgun has a randomangle of 20 (Because it fires multiple bullets) But my machinegun has the random of 4.